# Split Tunneling on an application level - Windows 10/11

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, internet-connection, split-tunnel

OS = Windows 11

I need to make use of a VPN to access a license server for software I want to run on my machine. The VPN itself is slow (internet wise) and cannot be configured/altered (i.e. cannot do split tunneling with the provided client). Additionally the software is very "pedantic" and needs to be connected to the license server continually.

I want to make it so that only the software that needs to communicate with the license server uses the VPN, and everything else does not. OR, failing that, that the entire machine uses the VPN except for my web browser (example being Firefox).

There have been similar questions asked, but without sufficient answers. As an example, one of the potential solutions is making use of WireGuard, but this is not an option in my situation.

EDIT:
The VPN software is Global Protect by Palo Alto - I have no ability at all to edit or alter the VPN client (restricted upstream).

Comment: so you need to be specific about the VPN software in use, and the capabilities you have to configure that software. ultimately this is likely an issue you will not be able to overcome without assistance from the administrators that manage the VPN/licensing server.

Comment: Are you allowed to install software on the computer? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: I have used split tunnel a lot. It is a function of the VPN setup. So without help from the people with the VPN setup, you most likely cannot do anything.

Comment: I am allowed to install software on the local computer, but not on the license server @harrymc .

Comment: So then my question is, @John, what happens behind the scenes with the VPN setup, and how does one replicate it 'manually', i.e. without the 'VPN people'?

Comment: So far as I know, you cannot.  VPN Split Tunnel is built in to the Client App if it is available at all.

Comment: The cleanest solution would be to run the application and its VPN in a virtual machine, so it will not impact upon the host computer. Another solution would be to run them in a sandbox so they will isolated from the host computer, using an application such as [Sandboxie](https://sandboxie-plus.com/). You will then need to change some settings if you wish the application to modify files outside of the sandbox.